# Multiple ui-select with separate selected values

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I have use the following to create several ui-select drop-down based on server data.  I like to select independent item from each drop-down.  When I select an item in one drop-down, all drop-downs get assigned the same value. How can I separate the selected values?

```
            <div ng-repeat="choiceItem in menuItem.mandatoryChoices">
            <ng-form name="innerModalForm1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label ng-show="choiceDescExist(choiceItem)">{{choiceItem.choiceDesc}}</label>

                    <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : innerModalForm1.option.$invalid && submitted }">
                        <div ng-show="choiceItem.multiSelect">
                            <ui-select name="mandatory" multiple required ng-model="selected.mandatoryChoices[$index]">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Please select one or more">
                                    {{$select.selected.choiceItemDesc}}
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="s in choiceItem.choiceOptions | filter: $select.search">
                                    <div ng-bind-html="s.choiceItemDesc | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="has-error" ng-show="submitted && innerModalForm1.option.$invalid">You must select this required item</span>
                </div>
            </ng-form>
        </div>
```

Here is a screenshot.  All three drop-downs has different set of values.

[image]

Comment: R u looking for this http://plnkr.co/edit/95wvJb?p=preview

Comment: Begin doing this: `<ui-select name="mandatory" required ng-model="choiceItem.selected">`. if it works, let's move on.

Comment: @Werlang, It did not work.  With the change you have suggested, do I need to change something in `{{$select.selected.choiceItemDesc}}` too?

Comment: Log all your model to console and see if model indeed share the same values

Comment: @Werlang, it works.  Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- `multiple` attribute: it is intended when a single select can have multiple selected values
- `ngModel` and `ng-repeat`/`$index`: while it can work, probably it is updating a wrong model

So the a better way is to do:

```
<ui-select name="mandatory" required ng-model="choiceItem.selected">
```

Also, when a have a complex expression in an `ng-model` I like to output my model to JSON:

```
{{ctrl.models | json}}
```